# Change UISlider value with swipe gesture swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uislider

I have a UIView with a swipe gesture .

```
 let swipeUpGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NextStepCaptureVC.handleSwipeUp(gesture:)))
        swipeUpGesture.direction = .up
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUpGesture)

func handleSwipeUp(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Swipe Up")
        heightSlider.setValue(20, animated: true)
    }
```

When I try to change the value it works but the value jump from 0 to 20.  I want the value to change continuously while swiping. How can I do it?

Comment: why are you using view and changing slider on basis of view's swipe? you can directly change the slider by swiping it!!!

Comment: I know that @KetanParmar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging from your code, it looks like you are trying to make 'panning up and down' on the screen translate to the `UISlider` value changing.

As already mentioned by others, first thing is to change your `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan(gesture:))) 
view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

Then in your pan function, you need to update the slider value based on how much the user has panned.

```
func pan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // The amount of movement up/down since last change in slider
    let yTranslation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view).y

    // The slide distance needed to equal one value in the slider
    let tolerance: CGFloat = 5

    if abs(yTranslation) >= tolerance {
        let newValue = heightSlider.value + Float(yTranslation / tolerance)
        heightSlider.setValue(newValue, animated: true)

        // Reset the overall translation within the view
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: gesture.view)
    }
}
```

Simply adjust the `tolerance` variable to make the user swipe more/less in order to adjust the slider value.

Comment: Your answer works but, the value change when I Pan down. How can I make it work when I Pan Up? Thanks @David

Comment: My answer works for both panning up and down. If you want to reverse the way it moves the slider... change `let newValue = heightSlider.value + Float(yTranslation / tolerance)` to `let newValue = heightSlider.value - Float(yTranslation / tolerance)`

Comment: @KerbyJean figuring out how to change the direction of the slider should not have been too difficult for you to figure out. I encourage you to make sure you actually understand everything about the code I have provided – try not to just copy and paste it :)

Comment: Ahah i'm a beginner but I will try :) Thanks

Comment: If my code has worked for you and provided you with the solution you were after, then please upvote it and mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, you want a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. A swipe is a one-time gesture.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/) says "A swipe is a discrete gesture, and thus the associated action message is sent only once per gesture."

Comment: That's so true, Thanks. But I how do I change the value continuously? I want the slider to animate live.

Comment: Use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: You use the delegate to get the touches, and you monitor them by the state start/end/progress

Comment: @Yitschak Can you give me an code example using a uislider? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Are you using a UISlider? If so, you don't need any gesture recognizer at all - the UISlider does all of the work. If you are using a UIView and creating a custom slider (not a UISlider), you use a PanGestureRecognizer. I don't have sample code, but the PanGestureRecognizer target's method gets called continuously as the user moves their finger. Read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

You set up a main action from your gesture recognizer to your code (You can use interface builder for that)

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
    } else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
    } else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed {
    }
}
```

Good luck! =]